# reinterpreting bolzano-weierstrass with equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, intuition, arzela-ascoli

Is there anything in the Bolzano-Weierstrass proof (for points in $\mathbb{R}^k$) that is analogous to using equicontinuity for functions in Arzela-Ascoli? Does the statement: "points are always equicontinuous" make sense? I feel that I may be forcing this reinterpretation, but I also feel that there might be some connection between the topology of points and the topology of a family of equicontinuous functions?

This question originiated from a previous [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307146/comparing-compactness-theorems-bolzano-weierstrass-and-arzela-ascoli/2307286#2307286!) in which one nice interpretation was offered:

> perhaps we can think of points as (trivially equicontinuous) constant functions

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this because you seem to have answered this question already. Points are constant functions. Arzela Ascoli is then a two dimensional form of BW, because you need both a bound on the interval and a bound on the functions. And the proof of Arzela Ascoli is effectively a direct consequence of BW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a point in $\mathbb R^k$ can be viewed as an element of $C(K)$, where $K$ is the compact set $ \{1, 2, \dots, k \}$. Since $\{1, 2, \dots, k \}$ is a finite union of discrete points, every function $\{1, 2, \dots, k \} \to \mathbb R$ is automatically continuous, so $C(K)$ does indeed correspond to the whole of $\mathbb R^k$. Furthermore, every family of functions $\{1, 2, \dots, k \} \to \mathbb R$ is automatically equicontinuous, so Arzela-Ascoli reduces to the statement that a subset of $C(K)$ has compact closure iff it is bounded.

[Note that if we think of $\mathbb R^k$ as $C(K)$ with $K = \{1,2,\dots,k \}$, then the natural norm on $\mathbb R^k$ would be the $l^\infty$ norm, rather than the Euclidean $l^2$ norm. However, all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space induce equivalent topologies, so this is not a problem.]

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a bit of trouble seeing this intuitively -- could you perhaps give a quick concrete example?

Comment: Are you asking for an example of how a point in $\mathbb R^k$ can be viewed as an element of $C(\{1,2,\dots, k \})$? Let's take the point $(4,8,21) \in \mathbb R^3$. We would identify this with the function $f: \{1,2,3 \} \to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(1) = 4$, $f(2) = 8$, $f(3) = 21$. To see that this $f$ is (uniformly) continuous, pick an $\epsilon > 0$. If we take $\delta = \frac 1 2$, then it's clear that $|x - y|< \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$; in fact, $|x - y| < \frac 1 2 \implies x = y \implies f(x) = f(y)$. Did I correctly understand your question?

Comment: Great, thanks that addresses the first part of my vague question. I guess I'm still hung up using this notation to describe a sequence (and subsequence) of points so that we can frame BW in terms of AA. So if we call our family of equicontinuous functions $\mathcal{F} \ni \{f_n\}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, where $f_n: \{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n(1) = p_n$, $f_n(2) = q_n$, $f_n(3) = r_n$ would we have $p_{n_j} \rightarrow 4$, $q_{n_k} \rightarrow 8$, $r_{n_l} \rightarrow 21$ for subsequences $p_{n_j}, q_{n_k},r_{n_l}$?

Comment: @jjjjjj  If your sequence of points in $\mathbb R^3$ has a convergence subsequence that converges to the point $(4,8,21) \in \mathbb R^3$, then, yes, your final sentence is exactly correct.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. One last thing to make concrete -- how might a sequence $p_n$ with subsequence $p_{n_j}$ be generated? It wouldn't depend on the $n$ indexing the family $\mathcal{F}$ right?

Comment: Are you asking how we choose the value of $n_j$ for each value of $j$?

Comment: Hm, before that, I think I'm confused about what $p_n$ would look like...

Comment: Suppose the sequence of points in $\mathbb R^3$ is $(4.1,8.1,21.1),(1,2,3),(4.01,8.01,21.01),(4.001,8.001,21.001),\dots$ Then $p_1 = 4.1$, $p_2 = 1$, $p_3 = 4.01$, $p_4 = 4.001$, etc, and $q_1 = 8.1,$, $q_2 = 2$, $q_3 = 8.01$, $q_4 = 8.001$ etc, and $r_1 = 21.1$, $r_2 = 3$, $r_3 = 21.01$, $r_4 = 21.001$ etc. In this example, we would define a convergent subsequence by taking $n_1 = 1, n_2 = 3, n_3 = 4, \dots$ (i.e. we skip the second term, but keep all others) Then $p_{n_j} \to 4$, $q_{n_j} \to 8$, $r_{n_j} \to 21$.

Comment: Ahh, so then for $j,k,l \geq N$ (for appropriate choice of $N$) we'd have $p,q,r$ "close enough"?

Comment: Once again, I'm afraid don't understand your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59763/discussion-between-kenny-wong-and-jjjjjj).